# How to draw this picture more simply

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw this picture more simply (with less code, or more reusable)?

[image]

[IMG click here](https://img-blog.csdnimg.cn/20210322195049447.jpg)

```tex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \p/\w in {0/2, 2/2, 4/1, 5/2, 7/2, 9/1, 10/1} {
    \draw[] (\p, 0) rectangle (\p+\w, 3-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {0/1, 1/2, 3/1, 5/1, 6/2, 8/1} {
    \draw[] (\p, 1) rectangle (\p+\w, 4-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {4/1, 9/2} {
    \draw[] (\p, 2) rectangle (\p+\w, 5-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {0/2, 2/2, 5/2, 7/1, 8/1, 9/2} {
    \draw[] (\p, 3) rectangle (\p+\w, 6-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {0/1, 1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 9/1, 10/1} {
    \draw[] (\p, 4) rectangle (\p+\w, 7-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {1/2, 3/1, 4/1, 5/2, 7/2} {
    \draw[] (\p, 5) rectangle (\p+\w, 8-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {0/2, 2/1, 5/2, 7/1, 8/2, 10/1} {
    \draw[] (\p, 6) rectangle (\p+\w, 9-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {0/1, 1/1, 3/1, 4/2, 6/1, 8/2} {
    \draw[] (\p, 7) rectangle (\p+\w, 10-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {2/1, 4/2, 7/1, 8/1, 9/2} {
    \draw[] (\p, 8) rectangle (\p+\w, 11-\w);
}

\foreach \p/\w in {0/2, 3/2, 5/2, 9/2} {
    \draw[] (\p, 9) rectangle (\p+\w, 12-\w);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could nest two `\foreach` loops:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a/\b in {
 0/{0/2, 2/2, 4/1, 5/2, 7/2, 9/1, 10/1}, 
 1/{0/1, 1/2, 3/1, 5/1, 6/2, 8/1}, 
 2/{1/2, 4/1, 6/2, 9/2}, 
 3/{0/2, 2/2, 5/2, 7/1, 8/1, 9/2}, 
 4/{0/1, 1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 9/1, 10/1},
 5/{1/2, 3/1, 4/1, 5/2, 7/2}, 
 6/{0/2, 2/1, 5/2, 7/1, 8/2, 10/1},
 7/{0/1, 1/1, 3/1, 4/2, 6/1, 8/2},
 8/{2/1, 4/2, 7/1, 8/1, 9/2},
 9/{0/2, 3/2, 5/2, 9/2},
} {
  \foreach \p/\w in \b {
    \draw (\p, \a) rectangle (\p+\w, 3+\a-\w);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I added two rectangles that where obviously missing in row 2. You could, of course, skip those rectangles that are implicitly drawn by others.

---

Variation that makes use of a counter (thanks for the hint!):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {
 {0/2, 2/2, 4/1, 5/2, 7/2, 9/1, 10/1}, 
 {0/1, 1/2, 3/1, 5/1, 6/2, 8/1}, 
 {1/2, 4/1, 6/2, 9/2}, 
 {0/2, 2/2, 5/2, 7/1, 8/1, 9/2}, 
 {0/1, 1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 9/1, 10/1},
 {1/2, 3/1, 4/1, 5/2, 7/2}, 
 {0/2, 2/1, 5/2, 7/1, 8/2, 10/1},
 {0/1, 1/1, 3/1, 4/2, 6/1, 8/2},
 {2/1, 4/2, 7/1, 8/1, 9/2},
 {0/2, 3/2, 5/2, 9/2},
} {
  \foreach \p/\w in \a {
    \draw[fill=yellow] (\p, \i) rectangle (\p+\w, 3+\i-\w);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Another variation that makes use of `pic`s:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 h/.pic = { \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(2,1); },
 v/.pic = { \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(1,2); }
]
\foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {
 {0/h, 2/h, 4/v, 5/h, 7/h, 9/v, 10/v}, 
 {0/v, 1/h, 3/v, 5/v, 6/h, 8/v}, 
 {1/h, 4/v, 6/h, 9/h}, 
 {0/h, 2/h, 5/h, 7/v, 8/v, 9/h},
 {0/v, 1/h, 3/h, 5/h, 9/v, 10/v},
 {1/h, 3/v, 4/v, 5/h, 7/h}, 
 {0/h, 2/v, 5/h, 7/v, 8/h, 10/v},
 {0/v, 1/v, 3/, 4/h, 6/v, 8/h},
 {2/v, 4/h, 7/v, 8/v, 9/h},
 {0/h, 3/h, 5/h, 9/h},
} {
  \foreach \p/\w in \a {
    \path pic at (\p, \i) {\w};
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Next try, type `s` to skip 1 place, `h` to place a horizontal rectangle and `v` to place a vertical one.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 h/.pic = { \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(2,1); },
 v/.pic = { \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(1,2); }
]
\newcounter{p}
\foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {
 {h, h, v, h, h, v, v},
 {v, h, v, s, v, h, v},
 {s, h, s, v, s, h, s, h},
 {h, h, s, h, v, v, h},
 {v, h, h, h, s, s, v, v},
 {s, h, v, v, h, h},
 {h, v, s, s, h, v, h, v},
 {v, v, s, v, h, v, s, h},
 {s, s, v, s, h, s, v, v, h},
 {h, s, h, h, s, s, h},
} {
  \setcounter{p}{0}
  \edef\theh{h}
  \edef\thes{s}
  \foreach \b in \a {
    \ifx\b\thes\else\path pic at (\thep, \i) {\b};\fi
    \ifx\b\theh\addtocounter{p}{2}\else\stepcounter{p}\fi
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I omit the variable  `\p`? Because very `\p` after the first one can calculate with `previous one + \w`.

Comment: `\p` is not always +1, sometimes you need to skip 1, but you can use the counter to go through the rows.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the value of current `\p` can calculate from prevoius `\p + \w`, and then with the initially `\p`, all other `\p` can omit, but I don't know how to write the calculation.

Comment: Well, this is true for the first line. But the problem is that you need to take into consideration vertical rectangles coming from the row below, You somehow need to store this information.

Comment: 好有道理啊~我没考虑到其他行不符合这个规律，你的第三段程序很神奇，学习了！

Comment: Segment No 4th is amazing! it left the coordinate out, easier to change to the other pic, Thanks!